# Run php script in background on nginx

Tags: php, background, automation

I'm trying to develop a payment module for one shop cms.
Payment is based on acquiring in a Bank.
So firstly for each order creates (with curl) a "ticket" on bank side. Ater that client is forwarded on payment page on bank server with its ticket id. If customer pays and push button "go back to store" everything is fine. 
But if customer pays and don't push this button i need to check the result (if he paid or not). It is also made by curl. I'm requesting info by ticket id and receive an array with parameters i need among them is result code i need to check.
So i need to check it automatically (for ex. 1 time each 5 mins during an hour).
Cron can't help me coz it is all dynamically processes. 
I created a function that returns me the result. But how can i start it in background with any interval?

Comment: Is it possible for the bank to give you a payment notification? That's how PayPal does it, so that you don't have to poll them continuously.

Comment: @Jack Yes it is best way. But currently bank sadly works only this way.

Answer (score 2):

Using cron. PHP does not offer anything like scheduler because it is out of scope of the language. You may use DB to store some of parameters needed to the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

I'll extend a little bit WebnetMobile answer on using cron for what you want.

Likely you have a table in your DB where you store are tickets you get from Bank and whenever they suceed or did not suceed as well the date the ticket was created.

Then, if what you want is to check every five minutes from bank ticket creation date whetever it suceed or not if unknown, you should run a cron **each minute** that will do the following:

1. Check if there are bank tickets without defined state (Suceed or Failed).
2. Check if time created (without seconds) minus current time (without seconds) MOD 5 == 0.
3. If true, means another 5 minutes period have passed from that ticket creation and should be checked, Else do nothing.

I think this will do what you want